# Is a short stay visa required for collecting boarding pass if office is located outside international zone?

Tags: visas, usa, air-travel, india, cdg

**Source**: LA Airport (USA)
**Destination**: Bangalore (India)
**Stop**: Paris (CDG airport)
**Type of flight**: Non-Connecting ( Two different tickets)
**Travelling Document**: Indian Passport
**Currently Holding Visa**: US F1 (Student)
**Baggage**: Only cabin baggage, No Check-In baggage, so I won't have to collect any baggage at the CDG Airport
**Time Difference between flight**: 6 Hours
When departing from US, I will only have a single boarding pass. So I need to collect my boarding pass from the airways office (Air India, Not sure about its location on the airport, whether in International/Outside)
**Ticket**: 2 separate tickets with different e ticket nos. And separate PNRs

I've tried contacting French Embassy, Indian Embassy, their twitter handles, multiple times, but to I haven't gotten a clear response, and this has made me more doubtful about the action to take.

**French Embassy**: French embassy says I won't require a visa if I don't leave international zone of Paris airport, otherwise I would require a short stay visa
**Paris Airport**: Paris airport says that to check in to my departure i.e. air india flight (which is on a separate terminal than my arrival Norwegian Airways flight), I would have to leave the international zone to collect my boarding pass for air india and hence would require a transit visa
**A travel agent**: As the Air India office in Paris Airport is outside the International Zone, you will need a Short Stay Visa.
**Internet**: From July 2018, Indians do not require transit visa in france

In my condition, there is no valid purpose of stay for short stay visa according to France visas website

Also Is there any other way to legally obtain my boarding pass without short stay, iff it is required ? I could not find any help on other forums, hence looking for an answer here. I have 15 days before I travel, and so will have to try best to get Visa, if required, as returns tickets are also booked.

**EDIT**:
In the ticket booked from kiwi.com, It is mentioned that online check-in is not available for this, so I will have to manually collect.

Comment: Have you checked whether you can check in to your Air India flight and print your boarding pass online?

Comment: According to http://www.airindia.in/paris.htm Air India have a transfer desk at CDG. A transfer desk is the airside equivalent of a check-in counter, and is able to issue boarding passes. It has pretty restrictive hours of operations, though, and there doesn't seem to be any information about where it is.

Comment: Don't know the exact situation regarding the need for transit visas for Indian citizens in Paris, but if you do need one, Norwegian may need some convincing to let you board in LAX. Not sure how hard or easy that is in they case.

Comment: You may want to call Air India's office in Paris (number listed here: https://www.parisaeroport.fr/passagers/les-vols/compagnies-aeriennes/AI) to ask where the transfer desk is and any restrictions to be aware of.

Comment: Thanks for the help @jcaron . It is mentioned in the ticket that online checkin is not available for the ticket (Paris to Delhi). So I will have to manually collect.
And about the Air India's office, it is still doubtful and I don't want to wait any longer, since its already too late. I will try to contact them again. Thanks for the contact.

Comment: Regarding transit visas: there is a requirement for citizens of some countries to get an Airport Transit Visa **even if they don't leave the international zone**. This is the requirement that has now been removed for Indian citizens. So, in your case, you don't need a visa if you can stay in the international zone (airside). You need a visa (which is not an airport transit visa, but a different kind of visa, I believe) if you have to exit the international zone (go landside).

Comment: Air India Paris office is best place to ask this or you can try calling CDG airport helpline and asking if airside transfer desks are there. If there aren't then you'lll need a Schengen short-stay visa (a multi entry one if you have the same itinerary on return).

Comment: @Giorgio Not a dupe (although the title may make it seem so). The OP seems to be aware that he doesn't need a visa if he stays airside. But he is not sure if Air India Boarding passes can be obtained without leaving the transit area.

Comment: Right @RedBaron, I saw that question before asking this.
I am still not sure about the process. Because one of the French Embassy Customer Support agreed that you do not need a visa for that. While If I again call that support, some other person disagrees. They themselves are not in unison. This is frustrating and scary.

Comment: @HarshSharma I would suggest you edit the title so that people do not flag it as duplicate. I don't think French Embassy can help you here. As I said in earlier comment, Paris airport guys or Air India (Paris) people can only tell you if they have an airside transfer desk where you can obtain boarding pass. If there indeed is airside transfer desk, I would suggest carrying a written confirmation so that you are not denied boarding at LAX

Comment: They are not ready to give a written confirmation.
I will edit the question title.

Comment: Visa-wise, as commented above, the situation is clear: if you stay airside (in the international zone), you no longer need a visa. If you need to go landslide (outside the international zone), you will need a visa (a full visa, not an airport transit visa). So the only questions are whether you can access the transfer desk airside, and whether Norwegian will let you board a flight to France without a visa valid for France (as far as they are concerned, your trip ends in Paris). I would personally recommend getting a visa if at all possible.

Comment: @jcaron, Thanks for the clarification. When applying for visa, there is no such `purpose` listed as `Transit` and there are obviously no `proofs of residence` with me. Acc. to a support member, I am filling `Paris Airport`, and only a single day of stay. And I also need to buy a `Travel Insurance Certificate`. -_-

Comment: "no valid purpose of stay": collecting a boarding pass is a perfectly valid purpose of stay.

Answer (score 3):

To answer the updated question title:

**If you do need to exit the international zone (airside), then you need a visa. Not an airport transit visa, but a regular one.**

**If** you can stay airside, then Indian citizens no longer require an airport transit visa (they used to need one even if they stayed airside, though there were exceptions).

To stay airside, you would need to:

- not have any checked luggage (which you stated is the case)
- be able to either do online check-in, or to reach a transfer desk which can issue the boarding pass for you.

[Air India has a transfer desk in CDG](http://www.airindia.in/paris.htm), however it is unclear where it is located, and its hours are restrictive. You should contact Air India for details.

Note that you would also have the issue of being able to board the first flight: as far as they know, Norwegian considers your flight ends up in Paris, so they may not let you board without a visa valid for France. Even if they accept the evidence that you are in transit and will stay airside, they may not be up-to-date with the relatively recent drop of the airport transit visa requirement.

The safest option is to get a visa. This will make sure you can do landside if you need to, and will satisfy Norwegian.

If you do not get a visa (having verified that you can get the boarding pass for the next flight while staying airside), then arrive early at LAX, and have all relevant documentation readily available, but be prepared for possible trouble. In the worst case, Norwegian may flatly refuse to let you board, and there wouldn't be much you could do about it.

Comment: I have often had boarding passes reprinted at the desk in front of the boarding gate.  Would it not be possible to collect an initial boarding pass directly at the gate?

Comment: @phoog I know some airlines do it, not sure if all do. But quite often nowadays, you can't even reach the gate without a boarding pass (mobile or paper), and I'm pretty sure that's the case even in transit.

Comment: In my experience (in NL, Germany, Austria), when one arrives in the international area, one can walk directly to one's next flight without showing the boarding pass before arriving at the gate.  So someone who has a next flight but not a boarding pass shouldn't have trouble reaching the departure gate, and, I suppose, be able to get the boarding pass printed there.  But I've never tried this (I rarely book connections on separate tickets, and when I have I've left an extra day to minimize the chance of missing the second flight).  I haven't transferred in France in several years, however.